# Is it possible to convert bootstrap tabs ti accordion in mobile view

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert bootstrap tabs to accordion in a particular screen size (<= 766px).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible with the help of bootstrap-tabcollapse.js. You basically need to mark up both the tabs and accordion code, and then give the tabs a `hidden-xs` class and the accordion a `visible-xs` class. Here's a Github link explaining the process and including a demo. https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse

Comment: Bootstrap 4 does not need https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse (really great help in older versions). It has generic support to make this accordion in mobile devices.